# Proof that this summation is equal to zero

Tags: summation

I'm developing a proof in statistics, and I came across this equation, which I want to prove is true:

$\sum_{i=1}^N a_{i} b_{i}=0$

$a_i \in \mathbb{R}$; $b_i \in \mathbb{R}$

I've already proved that $\sum_{i=1}^{N} a_{i}=0$ and $\sum_{i=1}^{N} b_{i}=0$

Is it possible to use these to prove the first equation?

Is there some summation property that applies to the summation of a product which could be useful here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, not in general. An example is $a=b=\{1,-1\}$.

Comment: Question edited. I originally wrote "natural numbers" where it should have been "real numbers"

Comment: It changes nothing about the fact that this statement is not true in general.

Comment: @GabrielFonsecaCunha Natural numbers are also real numbers. In particular $1$ and $-1$ are real numbers.

Comment: You might be looking at two "independent" distributions. If that's the case, the correlation (defined as $\mathbb E(ab)$ for demeaned random variables) is zero however this is really a treacherous assumption to make. It seems demeaned in your case as $\mathbb E(a)=\mathbb E(b)=0$.

Answer (score 2):

As @PC1 said in his comment, this is not true in general.

For example, let $N=4$ define your $a_i$ as $a_1=a_3=1,a_2=a_4=-1$ and your $b_i$ as $b_1=b_3=-1,b_2=b_4=1$.

Then: $$\sum_{i=1}^4 a_i=1-1+1-1=0$$ $$\sum_{i=1}^4 b_i=-1+1-1+1=0$$

but, for all $i$, $a_ib_i = -1$, so $$\sum_{i=1}^4 a_ib_i=-1-1-1-1=-4$$

Comment: Got it. Thank you.